# Arrays and malloc in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

Hello I am new to C and I need someone to explain concepts to me. I am a JAVA programmer and I am trying to write a program in C. My current issue is trying to initialize an array with an unknown number. I know in C an array has to be initialized with a number instead of a variable like you can in Java. My question is if I can do this in Java:

```
int i = 0;
char array [i];

void f(){
\\some code
i++;
}
```

How can I do this in C? I'm trying to fill an array with certain strings that I get from a file. I don't know how many I will be getting from the file however. I have tried reading about malloc but in one tutorial it says:

```
int *pointer;
pointer=malloc(2*sizeof(int));
```

is equivalent to

```
int array[2];
```

But I'm looking for a way to do this while increment the array.

Comment: When you `malloc` a zone, you'll need to `free` it later (unlike in Java which has a GC). Read some good C programming book.

Comment: I think you'd need to go back and rework this question. It's not very clear exactly what you want to do, as written.

Comment: They are far from equivalent. Delete the tutorial from your brain and blacklist the website you found it on.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/ this, and you might want to read a few pages about pointers. Great ur stepping away from java and trying some real programming!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First to mention, `malloc()` and family is used for dynamic (runtime) memory allocation whereas `int arr[2]` usually denotes compile time memory allocation. They are not exactly *equivalent*.

However, if you want to resize the allocated memory on-the-fly, you're on right track. What you need to do next is to use `realloc()` to re-size the previously allocated memory location.

You can read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) for more details.

Also, while using dynamic memory in `C`, you need to keep in mid that there is no *garbage collector* in `C`. You need to [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) up every bit of memory allocated by *you*.

Answer (score 0):

*I know in C an array has to be initialized with a number instead of a variable like you can in Java*
***In C99*** and beyond, ***[variable initiated arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)*** are available.

*My current issue is trying to initialize an array with an unknown number.*
***and***:
*But I'm looking for a way to do this while increment the array.*

If you have an unknown number of elements at run-time, you can write a function to create (and free) memory, passing the relevant arguments as you need them.  Here is an example of a function to create (and free) a 2 dimensional array of ints:

```
int ** Create2Dint(int **arr, int cols, int rows)
{   
    int space = cols*rows; 
    int    y;

    arr   = calloc(space, sizeof(int));
    for(y=0;y<cols;y++)
    {
        arr[y] = calloc(rows, sizeof(int)); 
    }
    return arr;
}  

void free2DInt(int **arr, int cols)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<cols; i++)
        if(arr[i]) free(arr[i]);
    free(arr);  
}
```

If, during execution, you need to change the allocation of memory (change the size of the array) you can use realloc(), implemented here in similar fashion:

```
int ** Realloc2D(int **arr, int cols, int rows)
{   
    int space = cols*rows; 
    int    y;

    arr   = realloc(arr, space*sizeof(int));
    for(y=0;y<cols;y++)
    {
        arr[y] = calloc(rows, sizeof(int)); 
    }
    return arr;
}
```

***Usage example:***
(execute with two integer command line arguments, both > 0)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int **array = {0};
    int cols, rows;

    cols = atoi(argv[1]);
    rows = atoi(argv[2]);

    array = Create2Dint(array, cols, rows);
    //Do stuff here to use array
    //Memory requirements change during runtime:
    cols += 20;
    rows += 50;

    array = Realloc2D(array, cols, rows);  
    //use array again...

    //When you are finished with the memory, free it: 
    free2DInt(array, cols);

    return 0;
}
```